# Texas Holdem Board deals a straight

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

Board deals a straight say 45678  Alice has K A 123 and Tom has K Q 123 does Alice win as her hole card is an Ace ? or do they split the pot ? TY

Comment: What is the best five card hand?

Comment: What version of Texas Hold'em has 5 cards on the board and also 5 card hands for players??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winner is player with best hand which means best set o 5 cards. In your example both players have 45678 as their hand so game is drawn and pot is splited.

Comment: The question only involves two players. Your use of terminology is poor, with the likely result of confusing people new to poker.

Comment: what difference does it make what the other six players had if they could not beat K A  or K Q hole cards ?

Comment: Cards beyond the five card best hand do not matter.  In the case where the 5 cards on the board are the best hand, all players who haven't folded split the pot.